# Using IEdmModel to resolve EntitySet name into EntityName (Products -> Product)

Tags: c#, .net, odata, wcf-data-services

I am using a OData Service on top of Entity Framework

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9876/Service.svc");
var context = new DataServiceContext(uri, , DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3);
var model = EdmxReader.Parse(
    XmlReader.Create(context.GetMetadataUri().AbsoluteUri)
);
context.Format.UseJson(model);
```

Now I need to figure out the entity name name from an EntitySet name

My entities are called `Product` or `Customer` but the Name of the `EntitySet` can be either `Products` or `CustomerSet` or something else.

Since I already loaded the `IEdmModel` and the information is located in the `$metadata` is there a way to resolve the entity name from the IEdmModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I haven't found a way to extract the information I want I ended up creating my own solution.

First I read the metadata xml into a string to only have a roundtrip to the service.
Then I create my `IEdmModel` from the string and create my own class which extracts all information from the metadata xml.

```
    var client = new WebClient();
    var metadata = client.DownloadString(metadataUri);
    var model = CreateModel(metadata);
    var schema = CreateSchema(metadata);

    private static IEdmModel CreateModel(string metadata)
    {
        using (var reader = new StringReader(metadata))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
        {
            return EdmxReader.Parse(xmlReader);
        }
    }

    private static Schema.Schema CreateSchema(string metadata)
    {
        using (var reader = new StringReader(metadata))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
        {
            var root = XElement.Load(xmlReader);
            return SchemaBuilder.GetSchema(root);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code to read the Schema from the metadata, hopefully someone will find this useful. I did not include the classes I use but they are just POCOS with no code.

```
    public static Schema GetSchema(XElement root)
    {

        XNamespace edmx = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("edmx");
        XNamespace edm = root.Element(edmx + "DataServices").Elements().First().GetDefaultNamespace();

        var result = from s in root.Element(edmx + "DataServices").Elements(edm + "Schema")
                     select new
                     {
                         Namespace = (string)s.Attribute("Namespace"),
                         EntityTypes = from e in s.Elements(edm + "EntityType")
                                       select new EntityType
                                       {
                                           Name = (string)e.Attribute("Name"),
                                           Key = from k in e.Element(edm + "Key").Elements(edm + "PropertyRef")
                                                 select (string)k.Attribute("Name"),
                                           Properties = from p in e.Elements(edm + "Property")
                                                        select new Property
                                                        {
                                                            Name = (string)p.Attribute("Name"),
                                                            Type = (string)p.Attribute("Type"),
                                                            Nullable = (bool)p.Attribute("Nullable", true),
                                                            MaxLength = (string)p.Attribute("MaxLength"),
                                                            FixedLength = (bool)p.Attribute("FixedLength", false),
                                                        },
                                           NavigationProperties = from p in e.Elements(edm + "NavigationProperty")
                                                                  select new NavigationProperty
                                                                  {
                                                                      Name = (string)p.Attribute("Name"),
                                                                      Relationship = (string)p.Attribute("Relationship"),
                                                                      ToRole = (string)p.Attribute("ToRole"),
                                                                      FromRole = (string)p.Attribute("FromRole"),
                                                                  }
                                       },
                         Associations = from a in s.Elements(edm + "Association")
                                        select new Association
                                        {
                                            Name = (string)a.Attribute("Name"),
                                            Ends = from et in a.Elements(edm + "End")
                                                   select new AssociationEnd
                                                   {
                                                       Type = (string)et.Attribute("Type"),
                                                       Role = (string)et.Attribute("Role"),
                                                       Multiplicity = (string)et.Attribute("Multiplicity"),
                                                   }
                                        },
                         AssociationSets = from @as in s.Elements(edm + "EntityContainer").Elements(edm + "AssociationSet")
                                           select new AssociationSet
                                           {
                                               Name = (string)@as.Attribute("Name"),
                                               Association = (string)@as.Attribute("Association"),
                                               Ends = from r in @as.Elements(edm + "End")
                                                      select new AssociationSetEnd
                                                      {
                                                          Role = (string)r.Attribute("Role"),
                                                          EntitySet = (string)r.Attribute("EntitySet"),
                                                      },
                                           },
                        EntitySets = from @es in s.Elements(edm + "EntityContainer").Elements(edm + "EntitySet")
                                     select new EntitySet
                                            {
                                                Name = (string)@es.Attribute("Name"),
                                                EntityType = (string)@es.Attribute("EntityType"),
                                            },

                     };

        return new Schema
        {
            Namespace = result.First().Namespace,
            EntityTypes = result.SelectMany(x => x.EntityTypes).ToDictionary(x => x.Name),
            Associations = result.SelectMany(x => x.Associations).ToDictionary(x => x.Name),
            AssociationSets = result.SelectMany(x => x.AssociationSets).ToDictionary(x => x.Name),
            EntitySets = result.SelectMany(x => x.EntitySets).ToDictionary(x => x.Name),
        };
    }
```